# please create subscriber to the marker (warn)

Tags: gazebo, rviz, master, ros-kinetic, marker

[image: Rosanswers logo]

i did:

```
rosrun using_markers basic_shapes
```

and got the warning:

```
please create a subscriber to the marker
```

I dont get it i want to create the basic shapes in rviz and i dont noe whats going on

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/250671/please-create-subscriber-to-the-marker-(warn)/) by [Abhinav Sonone](https://answers.ros.org/users/28155/abhinav-sonone/) on ROS Answers with karma: 25 on 2016-12-23

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The node is informing you that there is no subscriber for your markers. Just open RVIZ, and add the markers. If there is a subscriber, the basic_shapes node is going to start to publish the markers.

---

Originally posted by [NEngelhard](https://answers.ros.org/users/18581/nengelhard/) with karma: 3519 on 2016-12-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Abhinav Sonone](https://answers.ros.org/users/28155/abhinav-sonone/) on 2016-12-23**:
How do we add markers after opening RViz?
It also says that no tf data , Actual error no FIXED Frame exists

**Comment by [NEngelhard](https://answers.ros.org/users/18581/nengelhard/) on 2016-12-23**:
http://wiki.ros.org/rviz/UserGuide http://wiki.ros.org/rviz/Tutorials/Markers%3A%20Basic%20Shapes#Viewing_the_Markers